# If r, s and n are natural numbers and n>=2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, arithmetic

If $r, s$ and $n$ are natural numbers and $n\geq 2$ and
$r + s = 2n - 1$ show that $r\geq n$ or $s\geq n$.
I know that both can't be greater nor less than $n$ but I don't know how to prove that one have to be greater or equal to $n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: Try a concrete example.  Suppose $n = 5$.  Then $r+s = 2\cdot5-1 = 9$.  Isn't it impossible for neither $r$ nor $s$ to be greater than or equal to $5$?  If you see that, try to generalize.  The pigeonhole principle is helpful here.

Comment: The pigeonhole principal is useful, but so is averages.  The average of r and s is (r+s)/2 = (2n -1) = n - 1/2.  As that is no a whole number one term must be less than average and the other must be more than average.  More than average is $\ge n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this lemma: if $a \leq b$ and $c \leq d$, then $a + c \leq b + d$. I also assume that if $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $a < b \implies a \leq b - 1$. (Ask in the comments if this isn't obvious.)

Now assume $r < n$ and $s < n$ which means $r \leq n-1$ and $s \leq n-1$. Then $r + s \leq 2n - 2$ but $r + s = 2n - 1 > 2n - 2$ so we have a contradiction. Therefore either $r \geq n$ or $s \geq n$.

Answer (score 0):

Another method $avg(r,s) = \frac {r+s}2 = \frac {2n-1}2 = n - \frac 12$.

If one term is less than the average $n- \frac 12$, then the other term must be more than the average $n - \frac 12$.

===== or =====

$r + s = 2n -1$

$s + 1 = 2n - r$

If $r < n$ then

$s+ 1 = 2n - r > 2n - n = n$

So $s > n -1$ so $s \ge n$.

....

If $s < n$ then by the exact same proof $r \ge n$.

=====

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works also. But shouldn't be n instead of 4?

Comment: Aren't "n" and "4" the same curved simple.  Just as "G" and "5" are the same thing?  Or was that some weird idea I got when I was 5 years old?  I have no idea why I typed 4 instead of N.  They aren't even close on the keyboard.  But somehow I did that.  (When I was five I thought "G" and "5" were equivalent... I also thought "R" and "4" were equivalent... maybe some weird wiring in my brain that "R" and "N" were very close so....

Comment: That's fun lol, anyways I liked the proof.